# How to run assembly in gdb directly?

Tags: assembly, gdb

I can use `call` to run c functions ,but how to run assembly or even shell code directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To execute shell code, you can edit a function's contents directly:

```
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400608
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400608 in foo ()
(gdb) x/16bx foo
0x400604 <foo>:        0x55    0x48    0x89    0xe5    0x53    0x48    0x81   0xec
(gdb) set ((unsigned char *)foo)[6] = 0x85
(gdb) x/16bx foo
0x400604 <foo>:        0x55    0x48    0x89    0xe5    0x53    0x48    0x85   0xec
(gdb) cont
```

I don't know how to execute opcodes from within `gdb`, but you can certainly do whatever you want with registers. For instance, instead of `mov %rbx, %rax` you can use `set $rax = $rbx`:

```
(gdb) p $rax
$1 = 3671197290184
(gdb) set $rax = $rbx
(gdb) p $rax
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `let` and `set`?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, it's supposed to read `set`. I'll fix the post.

Comment: Is there a env like python shell for assembly code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gdb includes an assembler, so I wouldn't expect to be able to enter assembly directly.

You can use the `shell` gdb command to run shell commands:

```
(gdb) shell uname -m
x86_64
```

Comment: But in c we can embed assebmly directly,right? Here I mean stuff like `\x23\x24...` by the shell code

Comment: by "shellcode", compiler meant a specific kind of [binary code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) executed by the CPU.