# GDB: Assembly instruction calculation

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I'm new to assembly.  Is there a way to execute a calculation in GDB apart from the actual code being debugged?  For example, I'm stepping through the following using Linux IA-32 assembly (AT&T syntax):

```
   ;$esi is 0xbffff0a8 which refers to 1 after this command. $eax is 2
   0x08048cd5 <+42>:    lea    -0x20(%ebp),%esi

   ;$eax=ebx=2 after this instruction
   0x08048cd8 <+45>:    mov    %ebx,%eax 

   ;$eax equals 2 after this instruction               
   0x08048cda <+47>:    add    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
```

I'm just not seeing how $eax ends up at 2.  Can I assue an instruction like: -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4) in gdb and analyze the result?

As I understand it, $ebx is multiplied by 4 to yield 8.  That is added to $esi to give 9.  Then -4 is subtracted to give 5.  Then five is added to $eax which was 2 to yield 7.  Instead $eax is 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run assembly in gdb directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661021/how-to-run-assembly-in-gdb-directly)

Comment: @HostileFork, I guess you have to convert the instructions to shell commands.  I think I see the problem with my calculation.  The additions are to the address in $esi address, then the newly calculated address gets dereferenced and added to $eax.

Comment: @user994165, this is the difference `lea` and other instructions like `add`. For the latter, the effective address of a memory reference like `-0x4(%esi, %ebx, 4)` is calculated, the value pointed to by that address is then loaded into the CPU and added to `%eax`.

Comment: The instruction `add    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax` will do the following: `%ebx` is multiplied by 4 to yield 8, which is added to `%esi` to get `0xbffff0b0` from which 4 is subtracted to get an *address* of `0xbffff0ac`.  The data *from* that address is added to `%eax`. Presumably, the data at `0xbffff0ac` is zero.  But this doesn't answer your real question of how to evaluate assembly expressions in GDB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can evaluate expressions using registers, if that's what you're asking.

*gdb*'s `print` command is your friend.

Basically you can query the registers by prepending a dollar sign, e.g.

```
print $ecx
```

or use them in expressions:

```
print $esi + $ebx + 4
```

You can dereference the memory using the `*` operator (like in C):

```
print *$ecx
```

will print the contents of the memory location pointed to by `ecx`.

While you can't directly type in assembly code, you can translate the expression into something more high-level, like this:

```
print $eax - ($esi * $ebx)
```

Also, you can convert to various types using casts to C data-types, e.g.

```
print (char)$ecx
```

would print the contents of `ecx` as a character.

```
print *(char**)$ecx
```

which would interpret `ecx` as a pointer to `char*`, which you then dereference. So you'd see the contents of the string at the address contained in `ecx`.

This is just the tip of the iceberg though. *gdb* is very powerful tool. You might also find the `display` command useful. It's basically the same as `print`, except it will repeat the `print` command whenever the code is stopped (useful with breakpoints). You can examine most registers using `info registers`, or `info all-registers` if you're masochistic.

You can also change the contents of registers, using `set`:

```
set $eax = 20
```

and `stepi` through instructions, or `continue` running the program.

P.S. You'll probably want to learn how to set breakpoints, etc., if you don't know that.